# How to display dots (....) if content exceeds in html

Tags: html, css

I have tried using   text-overflow: ellipsis; this syntax but it's not working can any one help me

**Html**

```
   <div class="product-desc">
         <p>How to show dots if text is exceeds than the limit</p>
    </div>
```

**Style that i have used**

```
.product-desc{
    padding: 0.8em 1.5em;
    background: #337AB7;
    text-align: center;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.product-desc p{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    font-family: 'Carrois Gothic', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below:

```
.product-desc p{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    font-family: 'Carrois Gothic', sans-serif;
    width:180px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```